# How spark manages physical memory, virtual memory and executor memory?

Tags: apache-spark, memory

As I have been working on Spark for a few days, I get confused around spark memory management. I see terms like physical memory, virtual memory, executor memory, memory overhead and these values don't add up properly as per my current understanding. Can someone explain these things in terms of spark in a simple way?

E.g., I'm running a spark job with following configurations in cluster-mode:

```
spark_conf = SparkConf() \
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "10g") \
  .set("spark.executor.cores", 4) \
  .set("spark.executor.instances", 30) \
  .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", False)
```

But I get an error like this:

```
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2020-08-18 11:57:54.479]
Container [pid=96571,containerID=container_1588672785288_540114_02_000001] 
is running 62357504B beyond the 'PHYSICAL' memory limit. 
Current usage: 1.6 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 
3.7 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

How physical memory and virtual memory allocations are done w.r.t. executor memory and memory overhead?

Also when I run the same job in client-mode with the same configurations, it runs successfully. Why is it so? The only thing that gets changed in client-mode is the driver and I don't have any code which aggregates data to the driver.

Comment: 10g * 30 = 300g, Do you have? or might be the driver does not have enough memory?

Comment: Yes, the cluster has a total allocation of up to 500Gb. I tried to change driver's memory from 2GB to 64GB, but the error remains the same. And when I run this job in client-mode, my client machine has 64GB total RAM.

Comment: And the main question is why physical memory 1.5GB and why virtual memory 3.1Gb?

Comment: in general, pmem * 2.1 = vmem.

Comment: Thanks for the info!. But why the same driver memory works in client-mode but not in cluster-mode?

Answer (score 0):

When you see the option value,

```
yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio    2.1
```

the default ratio between physical and virtual memory is `2.1`. You can calculate the physical memory from the total memory of the yarn resource manager divide by number of containers, i.e executors without driver things.

Here is an [article](https://unraveldata.com/apache-spark-and-memory/) but there will be more good articles how yarn allocate the physical memory.